# Repertoire method in solving recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't know, how should I start solving this:
$$a_1 = 2 \\ a_n = 2a_{n-1} +7$$
using the repertoire method.

Could anyone give me an algorithm or explain, how to use this method in this case?

Comment: You may want to see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017498/mathematical-explanation-for-the-repertoire-method) for a thorough explanation.

Comment: The problem is that in this explanation we dont have the $a_{n-1}$ multiplied by 2. I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: @Kuba: Make it $a_1=\alpha$ and $a_n=2a_{n-1}+\beta$. This has an easy solution when $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=0$; that gives you one of the building blocks. You can get the other one by considering the case $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=1$.