# Question about repertoire method example: performing linear combinations.

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

In @MarkusScheuer's excellent answer on [Mathematical Explanation for the Repertoire Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1023510/109665) the introduction gives a concrete example with two provided repertoire items, $x_n$ and $y_n$ which are then linearly combined to find the solution to $z_n$. Quoting that section below:

> To make it more concrete, let $a_n = 3$ and $b_n = 5n^2 + 1$. Assuming we know the solutions of $x_n$ and $y_n$ of the recurrences
>
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> x_0&=3&y_0&=1\\
> x_n&=3+x_{n-1},\quad n>0&y_n&=5n^2+1+y_{n-1},\quad n>0
> \end{align*}
> $$
>
> then we also know *by linearity* that the solution of the recurrence
>
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> z_0&=7\\
> z_n&=2n^2+7+z_{n-1}
> \end{align*}
> $$
>
> is
>
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> z_n=\frac{11}{5}x_n+\frac{2}{5}y_n
> \end{align*}
> $$

To find the eventual closed form cooefficient for the $n^2$ variable (say $\beta$) I think we do the following

$$
\begin{align}
2 &= \beta 5 \\
\frac25 &= \beta
\end{align}
$$

to use with $y_n$. However I have not been able to figure out how to arrive at $\frac{11}{5}$. I am not sure how to "map" the constant in recurrence $x_n = 3 + x_{n-1}$ to the $7$ in recurrence $z_n$ as well as take into account the $1$ in $y_n = 5n^2 + 1 + y_{n-1}$. I suspect I'm overthinking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $z_n=\alpha x_n+\beta y_n$ for $n=0, 1$ to get the equations $3\alpha+\beta=7$ and $6\alpha+7\beta=16$. Solving for $\alpha,\beta$ gives $\alpha=11/5, \beta=2/5$.